# I want to scrape all pages, current page is scraped but please can you add next page code in which?

Tags: vba

```
Option Explicit
Public Function GetLastRow(ByRef ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
++++++++++++
Public Function TidyString(ByVal inputString As String) As String
    TidyString = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(inputString)
    TidyString = Trim$(Replace$(Replace$(TidyString, Chr$(10), vbNullString), vbCrLf, vbNullString))
End Function
++++++++++++
Public Sub ApplyHeaders(ByVal wsTarget As Worksheet)
    Dim headers(), i As Long
    headers = Array("Manufacturer Part No", "Order Code", "Manufacturer / Description", "Availability", "Price For", "Price Ex. VAT (Inc. VAT)")
    For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
        wsTarget.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = headers(i)
    Next i
End Sub
+++++++++++++
Public Function WaitUntilReady(ByVal IE As InternetExplorer) As HTMLTable
    With IE
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
            Set WaitUntilReady = .document.getElementById("sProdList")
            On Error GoTo 0
        Loop While WaitUntilReady Is Nothing
    End With
End Function
++++++++++++
Public Sub TidySheet(ByVal wsTarget As Worksheet)
    With wsTarget
        .Rows("2:" & .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row).RowHeight = 25
        .UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
+++++++++++++
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer, a As HTMLTable, wsTarget As Worksheet, currSearch As Long, searchTerms
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    wsTarget.UsedRange.ClearContents
    searchTerms = Array("Monitors")
    
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        ApplyHeaders wsTarget
        For currSearch = LBound(searchTerms) To UBound(searchTerms)
            .navigate "http://cpc.farnell.com/search?st=" & searchTerms(currSearch) & "&aka_re=1"
 
            Set a = WaitUntilReady(IE)

            Dim allRows As Object, classNames()
            Set allRows = a.getElementsByClassName("productRow")
            classNames = Array("productImage mftrPart", "sku", "description enhanceDescClmn", "availability", "priceFor", "priceBreak")
    
            Dim i As Long, y As Long, r As Long, tempString As String, j As Long, k As Long
            r = GetLastRow(wsTarget, 1) + 1
           
            For i = 0 To allRows.Length - 1
                For j = LBound(classNames) To UBound(classNames)
                    For k = 0 To allRows(i).getElementsByClassName(classNames(j)).Length - 1
                        tempString = tempString & vbNewLine & TidyString(allRows(i).getElementsByClassName(classNames(j))(k).innerText)
                    Next k
                    With wsTarget
                        .Cells(r, j + 1).Value = tempString
                    End With
                    tempString = vbNullString
                Next j
                r = r + 1
            Next i
            r = r + 1
        Set Docm = Nothing
        Next currSearch
        
        .Quit
    End With
    
    TidySheet wsTarget
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Add automate web page navigation

Comment: Welcome to the board.  Could you have a read of [ASK] and [MCVE] please.  I can kind of see the question - something about "next page code", but you haven't explained where your existing code is going wrong or what it does in the first place.  There's an _edit_ button at the bottom of your question to add further details.

Comment: Welcome ahmalli123! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!